# How can I make a reusable razor view that requires generic expressions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The MVC templates generate views that display each field like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Name, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name, New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

There's one of these for each property--only the property name changes--and a set of these for each type of entity. I'd like to put this into a reusable partial view, but the problem is that the expression depends on the model type, and you can't have a generic view. So I have dozens of these in my app and keeping them in sync as my styles change is a pain.

So how could I modularize the view so I could just pass in the expression like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Edit Property", Function(model) model.Name)
```

Or is there a more general solution to this problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Sounds like modifying the code templates (scaffolding) might be a good alternative.  You can create project-specific scaffolds for edit,  details,  list and other templates. You could also generate T4 template (or use MVC scaffold package) to keep them up to date.

Comment: That would mean that the templates are auto-generated, so that there would still be multiple copies of everything, although they wouldn't have to be manually updated. But it still seems like there ought to be a way to have one actual reusable template.

Comment: Cam you provide a delta in terms of actual versus expected outcome (show what's falling short and what type trying to achieve? )

Comment: @BradChristie: What's falling short is that I don't want dozens of instances of the markup in my question, one for each thing you want to edit, because that would be hard to maintain. I want to be able to define that layout once, but be able to reuse it for any model property.

Answer (score 0):

Use editor templates. I've got a [write up on my blog here](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/), but the TL;DR version is for each type of thing (could be a type, class or value; one of the members of the `DataType` enum; or virtually anything you want via `UIHint`), you create a partial view in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`. Inside those views you can put whatever HTML you'd like rendered when calling `Html.EditorFor` with a property.

For example, if you had a property:

```
public DateTime Foo { get; set; }
```

And you added the following partial view at `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBox("", New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("", "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, all you'd have to do in your view is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo)
```

And all the HTML would be rendered.

Comment: I do use templates, but it doesn't address the problem, because each template then repeats the markup. I'm trying to make it so that you can reuse the label, textbox, and validation arrangement without duplication.